# Copy file from UWP resources to local folder

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to copy a file from the UWP resources into the user's local folder.

The closest I could get was this:

```
public static void CopyDatabaseIfNotExists(string dbPath)
{
        var storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        if (storageFile.FileExists(dbPath))
        {
            return;
        }

        using (var resourceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("preinstalledDB.db", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
        {
            using (var fileStream = storageFile.CreateFile(dbPath))
            {
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytes = -1;

                while ((bytes = resourceStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    fileStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work anymore with UWP.
GetResourceStream isn't available anymore ("Application doesn't contain a definition for 'GetResourceStream'").

Could somebody please tell me how do this with UWP?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it a bit simpler, just replace `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` with your desired folder.

```
try
{
    await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("preinstalledDB.db");
    // No exception means it exists
    return;
}
catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
{
// The file obviously doesn't exist
}

// Cant await inside catch, but this works anyway
var storfile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///preinstalledDB.db"));
await storfile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
```

The `try` block may seem strange but it is actually the fastest way to determine if a file exists.

Comment: Thank you, but my void is  public static void CopyDatabaseIfNotExists(string dbPath). It doesn't allow the await operator. Is there a way to use the await operator anyways?

Comment: Also, await is asynchronous, right? This means that the void will return immediately, right? I'm not sure if that is really what I need. Could you perhaps share some insights on how your code can be used?

Comment: Yes, you need to make the method async and await it. No way around it.

Comment: But there's a chance that this method succeeds only after I tried to open the database, right???

Comment: Side note: Since C# 6 it's possible to await in catch.

Comment: @IgorKulman I really wonder how you would use this code in production. This void expects the tasks (like copying the file from the resources to the local folder) to be finished when you leave it. Your await / async approach doesn't meet this requirement. Or am I totally wrong?? Looking at your high ranking I think that it's probally ME who didn't understand something.

Comment: change your method from `void` to `async Task`, use my code in it and just use it like any other task, awaiting it. Nothing special about it.

Comment: @IgorKulman But changing my void to an async task means that my "void" is run async, right? Or does the await mean that it (in the end) will basically be sync? Sorry for the many questions.